# How to uppercase the first char of a substring only if it has more than 3 chars length

Tags: sed, tr

I need to transform this string:

> my name is user from here not there.

to:

> My Name **is** User From Here **not** There

The details are, I need to upstring the first char of any word with more than 3 chars. Just it. I'm trying without success with this commands:

```
echo $FOO | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g"
```

Everything else should be lowercase.

Comment: While seeing your profile got to know you never select any answer as correct one, kindly give it sometime and when you have some answers try to select anyone of them as correct one too.

Comment: Your question title says more than 2, but the body asks about more than 3. Please [edit] to make this consistent, or clarify.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, my question was poorly formulated, I guess now is more clear. About selecting the correct answer RavinderSingh13, you are correct, but in my old question I was still looking for more answers because none of them could solve the problem, but I guess nobody is going to answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^\w+|\b\w{4,}\b/\u&/g' file
```

Upper-case the first character of a word if that word appears in a line that starts with a word or any word 4 or more characters long

Comment: At first glance this didn't seem much different [my `sed` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229424/6136214), but the `|` and single replacement are clear improvements.  A tweak -- replace `^\w+` with `^.` and it still works.

Comment: Works really well. As I sayd in agc answer, I had to lowercase everything before apply your sed filter, or sentences like My NAME IS NOT sMITH, would not work. Sorry about my ignorance. I understood until the last \b, but how does \u& works? I tried a lot of different combinations but without success.

Comment: @Otavio `\u&` makes the first character of the string that matched in the LHS of the substitute command, upper-case.

Answer (score 2):

Using *GNU* `sed`, (and `bash`):

```
F="my name is user from here not there."
sed -E 's/^./\u&/;s/([[:space:]])([[:alpha:]]{4})/\1\u\2/g' \ 
    <<< "${F,,}"
```

or:

```
sed -E 's/^./\u&/;s/(\s)(\w{4})/\1\u\2/g' <<< "${F,,}"
```

Output:

```
My Name is User From Here not There.
```

---

Notes:

`"${F,,}"` is a `bash` [case modification parameter expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/260721/165517), it returns a lower-case version of `$F`, which becomes the input for `sed`.

*GNU* `sed` offers some useful [synonyms and abbreviations](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) for common *regex* character classes.  The character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be abbreviated as `[[:alpha:]_]`, or simpler yet `\w`.

Even though `\u` looks like a *regex* abbreviation, it's not.  It's a ["special sequence"](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) used only in `s`*ubstitute* command replacement text -- `\u` means *"turn the next character to uppercase"*.

`&` refers to whatever the first *regexp* in the `s`*ubstitute* command matched. Compare the following:

```
sed 's/./&/'          <<< foo  # outputs "f"
sed 's/./&/g'         <<< foo  # outputs "foo"
sed 's/./&&&&/g'      <<< foo  # outputs "ffffoooooooo"
sed 's/./\u&&&\u&/g'  <<< foo  # outputs "FffFOooOOooO"
sed 's/.*/&&&&/'      <<< foo  # outputs "foofoofoofoo"
```

See the [*GNU* `sed` info pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for more details.

Comment: Perfect! I had to add `tr '[:upper:]'  '[:lower:]'` first, than use your solution or it would be not generalist as I need. I really search in sed documentation but I could not understand how those groups work (\w{4}) \b, \u, \s, Why a slash and a number after \u for example, or &. \w means any word? is like regexp? Could you explain a little?

Comment: @Otavio, See revised more general answer -- the `tr` addition should no longer be necessary.

Comment: Thank you! Using what yo said in Notes, I resumed the commando to `echo $SENTENCE | sed -E 's/./\l&/g;s/^./\u&/;s/(\b)(\w{4})/\1\u\2/g'`. Without using tr. Would like to use pearl, for portability, as triplee said, but had no success.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
echo "my name is user from here not there." |
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    if(length($i)>3){$i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)}}
    1'
```

Result:

```
my Name is User From Here not There.
```

Comment: Thank you @tripleee for editing it, I forgot to add one-liner form of solution.

Comment: Thank you! Works fine except for the first word that should have the first char in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

`tr` is not really the right tool for this job; it does not know about context at all.

Some variants of `sed` have Perl or `vi` regex extensions, but this cannot really be portably solved with `sed`, either.

Perl to the rescue:

```
bash$ foo="my name is user from here not there."

bash$ echo "$foo" | perl -pe 's/\w{4,}/\u$&/g'
my Name is User From Here not There.
```

This does what you are actually asking, but not what you want. Perhaps add a condition to upcase the first word of the input separately ... or switch to a library like [Lingua::EN::Titlecase](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Titlecase).

Notice also how we [do not use upper case for our private variables](/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) (because uppercase variables are reserved for system use) and [always quote our shell strings.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Works fine, except for the first word as you said. Perl seems a good option to replace sed, as I want in the future to use those scripts in mac osx. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Changing the regex to `^\w+|\w{4,}` takes care of capitalizing any initial letter too if you want that.